# Function meant to remove instances in a list without 1 in them doesn't work

Tags: python, list

The function below is meant to remove from a list of ascending prime numbers instances of a number without the digit 1 in it

```
def if_not_contains_1_remove(list_temp):
    for i in list_temp:
        stays = False
        for j in str(i):
            if j == '1':
                stays = True
        if not stays:
            print(i)
            list_temp.remove(i)
    print(list_temp)
    return list_temp
```

`list_temp` is:
`[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101, 103, 107, 109, 113, 127, 131, 137, 139, 149, 151, 157, 163, 167, 173, 179, 181, 191, 193, 197, 199, 211, 223, 227, 229, 233, 239, 241, 251, 257, 263, 269, 271, 277, 281, 283, 293, 307, 311, 313, 317, 331, 337, 347, 349, 353, 359, 367, 373, 379, 383, 389, 397, 401, 409, 419, 421, 431, 433, 439, 443, 449, 457, 461, 463, 467, 479, 487, 491, 499, 503, 509, 521, 523, 541, 547, 557, 563, 569, 571, 577, 587, 593, 599, 601, 607, 613, 617, 619, 631, 641, 643, 647, 653, 659, 661, 673, 677, 683, 691, 701, 709, 719, 727, 733, 739, 743, 751, 757, 761, 769, 773, 787, 797, 809, 811, 821, 823, 827, 829, 839, 853, 857, 859, 863, 877, 881, 883, 887, 907, 911, 919, 929, 937, 941, 947, 953, 967, 971, 977, 983, 991, 997]`

But unfortunately it returns:
`[3, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 29, 31, 41, 47, 59, 61, 71, 79, 89, 101, 103, 107, 109, 113, 127, 131, 137, 139, 149, 151, 157, 163, 167, 173, 179, 181, 191, 193, 197, 199, 211, 227, 233, 241, 251, 263, 271, 281, 293, 311, 313, 317, 331, 347, 353, 367, 379, 389, 401, 419, 421, 431, 439, 449, 461, 467, 487, 491, 503, 521, 541, 557, 569, 571, 587, 599, 601, 613, 617, 619, 631, 641, 647, 659, 661, 677, 691, 701, 719, 733, 743, 751, 761, 773, 797, 811, 821, 827, 839, 857, 863, 881, 887, 911, 919, 937, 941, 953, 971, 983, 991]`

which clearly contains numbers without the digit 1 in it like 3 or 7 or 887.

What is the mistake?

Comment: Do you want to remove 11 or keep 11? There seems to be some ambiguity between the name of your method and `stays = True`